# Не добавляются кнопки Телеграм, Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

```
from telebot import TeleBot, types

token = "&)*(^(^&JB!@#$%"
bot = TeleBot(token)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message: types.Message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Магазин гемов")
    btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("Открыть бесплатный ящик")
    markup.add(btn1, btn2)
    bot.send_message(
        message.chat.id,
        text=" Привет, это бот с продажей гемов для игры Brawl Stars.\n"
             "Но вы так же можете испытать удачу и открыть бесплатный ящик с гемами".format(message.from_user),
        reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def func(message: types.Message):
    if message.text == "Открыть бесплатный ящик":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        photo = open("C:/Users/miroa/Documents/rght/bot_leon/free_gems.jpg", "rb")
        my = types.KeyboardButton("Забрать")
        markup.add(my)
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo,
                       caption='Поздравляем, вы выиграли 550 \nЖми кнопку «Забрать»',
                       reply_markup=markup)
    elif message.text == "Магазин гемов":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        gem80 = types.KeyboardButton("80-99₽")
        gem170 = types.KeyboardButton("170-199₽")
        gem360 = types.KeyboardButton("360-379₽")
        gem530 = types.KeyboardButton("530-529₽")
        markup.add(gem80, gem170, gem360, gem530)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                         text="Ты попал в наш магазин, выбери товар который хочешь купить ",
                         reply_markup=markup)

    elif message.text == "Забрать":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        photo1 = open("C:/Users/miroa/Documents/rght/bot_leon/teg_bw.jpg", "rb")
        bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, photo1,
                       caption="Введите тэг своего аккаунта Brawl Stars\n"
                               "Пример: #VLLQ9GOR\n"
                               "Узнать свой тэг вы можете в профиле игры, пример на фото:",
                       reply_markup=markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, func1)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def func1(message: types.Message):
    if '#' in message.text:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Отлично, мы получили ваш тэг, проверьте его ещё раз и подтвердите правильность данных.")                 
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        true = types.KeyboardButton("✅Тэг правильный")#вот эти кнопки не добавляются
        false = types.KeyboardButton("❌Я ошибся")
        markup.add(true, false)
    elif message.text == "✅Тэг правильный":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"АБОБА.")


bot.infinity_polling(skip_pending=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что вы не прикладываете их к сообщению. Воспользуйтесь параметром [`reply_markup`](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI#reply-markup):

```py
if '#' in message.text:                
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    true = types.KeyboardButton("✅Тэг правильный")
    false = types.KeyboardButton("❌Я ошибся")
    markup.add(true, false)

    bot.send_message(
        message.chat.id,
        "Отлично, мы получили ваш тэг, проверьте его ещё раз и подтвердите правильность данных.",
        reply_markup=markup
    )
```

Comment: Тогда назревает вопрос.
def buy(message: types.Message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    if (message.text == "✅Тэг правильный"):
        bot.send_message(message.from_user,"Покупка по ссылке ",reply_markup=markup)
на Тэг правильный он вообще не реагирует

Comment: @МирославАлексеев Мне довольно сложно по маленькому отрывку кода в комментарии понять, в чём у вас сейчас проблема. Если вопрос с выводом кнопок решён, но у вас есть новый, пожалуйста, создайте новый вопрос. Или на крайний случай дополните текущий, нажав под ним кнопку "править"

Comment: Я создал новый вопрос 
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1420000/pytelegrambotapi-%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83