# PyTelegramBotAPI. Не реагирует на кнопку

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def func1(message: types.Message):
    if '#' in message.text:                
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        true = types.KeyboardButton("✅Тэг правильный")
        false = types.KeyboardButton("❌Я ошибся")
        markup.add(true, false)

        bot.send_message(
            message.chat.id,
            "Отлично, мы получили ваш тэг, проверьте его ещё раз и подтвердите правильность данных.",
            reply_markup=markup
        )
def buy(message: types.Message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    if message.text == "✅Тэг правильный":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user,"Покупка по ссылке ",reply_markup=markup)#почему?(

bot.infinity_polling(skip_pending=True)
```

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, на [официальный пример последовательной обработки сообщений](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py). Это может быть удобнее, чем использование единого обработчика

Answer (score 0):

Функция `buy` не является обработчиком сообщения. Но даже если вы сделаете её обработчиком, она не будет работать, потому что может быть только один обработчик для команды.

Вы должны добавить проверку в существующий обработчик `func1`:

```py
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def func1(message: types.Message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)

    if message.text == "✅Тэг правильный":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Покупка по ссылке ", reply_markup=markup)

    elif '#' in message.text:                
        true = types.KeyboardButton("✅Тэг правильный")
        false = types.KeyboardButton("❌Я ошибся")
        markup.add(true, false)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Отлично, мы получили ваш тэг, проверьте его ещё раз и подтвердите правильность данных.", reply_markup=markup)
```

Comment: спасибо, большое